# Return and print in functions

Tags: python, function, return

I would like to ask the difference between return and print.

```
def x(n):
    a=1
    print a,n,
    return a
print x(2)
```

If I type `x(2)` it will output on the console: `1 2` right?
Is the variable a printed a second time only when I type `print x(2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
print X(2)
```

then the function `X` gets called with 2 as a parameter, let's go inside it:

```
a=1
print a,2,
return a
```

it'll print 1 and 2, then it returns `a` which has the value 1.

The returned value (1) gets printed since you wrote `print X(2)`.

If you have wrote `X(2)` (without `print`), you would get `1` and `2` printed, and the returned value will be unused.

Answer (score 0):

```
def x(n):
    print n+1
```

Now, when `x(5)` is called, it will print `6` to the console. However, if you did `y=x(5)`, the value of `y` would be `None`.

Now:

```
def x(n):
    return x+1
```

If you called `x(5)`, it would still print `6` to the console. But, if you did `y=x(5)`, the value of `y` would be `6`, not `None`

Answer (score 0):

The two appear to do similar things, but are quite different.

Most of the time, you'll be using return as an output for a function. Using print implies just that: printing something as a string (perhaps to a file or interpretor, etc).

Also, you can't do anything with a value printed by a function. Returning a value provides you more in this regard since it isn't "garbage collected" like a printed value.

Return also allows you to break out of a function.

```
>>> def x(y):
...     squared = y ** 2
...     return squared
... 
>>> x(2)
4
>>> z = x(2)
>>> z
4
>>> def a(b):
...     squared = b ** 2
...     print(squared)
... 
>>> a(2)
4
>>> c = a(2)
4
>>> c
>>>
```

In this example, I have two functions: x and a. Both take one positional argument and either return or print that valued squared.

Notice that if I assign the function with an argument to a variable, I can return that value by calling the variable with the function returning a value but not with a function printing the value.